# Toggle button slide animation

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-animations, angular2-forms

I am trying to implement sliding button using 2 tabs onclick of button it should slide and show the other state (on->off & off->on) this is working perfectly but i need to add sliding animation to change this  I am using angular 2 
Any help is appreciated code snippet is given below .

```
  <div class="tog-button" [hidden]=!showOnbutton>
  <div class="tog-button-off" (click)="showOnbutton = !showOnbutton;updateValues()">
  <div class="line-bar"></div>
  <div class="line-bar"></div>
  <div class="line-bar"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="tog-button-on">
    ON  
  </div>
</div>

<div class="tog-button-black" [hidden]=showOnbutton>
  <div class="tog-button-on-state" (click)="showOnbutton = !showOnbutton;updateValues()">
    <div class="line-bar"></div>
    <div class="line-bar"></div>
    <div class="line-bar"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="tog-button-off-state">
    OFF
  </div>
</div>
```

below css is used for styling

```
.tog-button-black{
        height: 37px;
        margin: 6% 21% 5% 24%;
        /* border: solid 1px #E86056; */
        /* background-color: #FFFFFF; */
        /* background-color: #B2B2B2; */
        background-color: #B2B2B2;
        // -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(114, 114, 114, 0.5);
        // box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(114, 114, 114, 0.5);
        /* background-color: #B2B2B2; */
        padding: 2px; 
       // padding-left: 15%;
        .line-bar{
            box-sizing: border-box;
            border: 1px solid #E8E8E8;
            width: 1px;
            height: 15px;
            /* margin: 0px auto; */
            float: left;
            /* text-align: center; */
            margin: 4px 0px 0px 7px;
        }

        .tog-button-on-state{

            height: 33px;
            width: 48%;
            text-align: center;
            /* background-color: #E86056; */
            color: white;
            /* background-color: #E86056; */
            /* -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 103% 122%, 87% 0%, 0 0%); */
            clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 103% 122%, 87% 0%, 0 0%);
            float: left;
            background-color: white;
            color: #E8E8E8;
            padding-top: 6px;
            padding-left: 12%;
        }

        .tog-button-off-state{
            webkit-clip-path: polygon(17% 100%, 103% 125%, 100% 0%, 0 0%);
            clip-path: polygon(17% 100%, 103% 125%, 100% 0%, 0 0%);
            /* background-color: #e2dcdc; */
            width: 52%;
            float: right;
            text-align: center;
            height: 33px;
            /* background-color: #B2B2B2; */
            padding-top: 8px;
            color: white;
            //padding-left: 11%;

        }


    }




        .tog-button{
        ///height: 33px;s
        margin: 6% 21% 5% 24%;
       // -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(85, 85, 85, 0.5), 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
       // box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(85, 85, 85, 0.5), 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        //ackground-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(-57deg, #fffefe 51%, transparent 0%);
        border: solid 1px #E86056;

    .tog-button-on{
        height: 32px;
        width: 55%;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: #E86056;
        color: white;
       // background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(196deg, #fffefe 8%, transparent 0);
        /* background-color: #E86056; */
        -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 103% 122%, 87% 0%, 0 0%);
        clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 103% 122%, 87% 0%, 0 0%);
        padding-top: 8px;
       }

    .tog-button-off{
        background-color: white;
        height: 30px;
        width: 51%;
        float: right;
        text-align: center;
        color: #E8E8E8;
        padding: 3px;
        padding-left: 15%;
        /* border: 1px solid #E8E8E8; */
        .line-bar{
            box-sizing: border-box;
            border: 1px solid #E8E8E8;
            width: 1px;
            height: 15px;
            /* margin: 0px auto; */
            float: left;
            /* text-align: center; */
            margin: 4px 0px 0px 7px;
        }

    }




    }
```

Comment: added css styles

Answer (score 0):

Since you are hiding and showing two different html codes for ON and OFF , it would be hard to attain animation for the same. You can attain the same functionalities using a single html section using angular2, with which you could do animation too.
Please try the below code. It worked for me.

toggle.component.html

```
    <div class="myContainer">
       <div class="tog-button" [ngClass]="{'Off':!showOnbutton,'On':showOnbutton}">
         <div class="tog-button-off"  (click)="showOnbutton = !showOnbutton;updateClick();">
         </div>
         <div class="tog-button-on" [ngClass]="{'On':showOnbutton,'Off':!showOnbutton}" (click)="showOnbutton = !showOnbutton;updateClick();">
           {{clickData}}
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

toggle.component.ts

```
export class ToggleComponent {
   private showOnbutton:boolean = true;
   private clickData:string = "ON";

   constructor(){
     this.clickData = "ON";
     this.showOnbutton = true;
   }

   private updateClick(){
      if(this.showOnbutton){
          this.clickData = "ON";
      }else{
          this.clickData = "OFF";
      }
   }
}
```

toggle.css

```
.myContainer{
      width:100px;
}


.tog-button{
      height: 37px;
      // -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(85, 85, 85, 0.5), 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
      // box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(85, 85, 85, 0.5), 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
      //background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(-57deg, #fffefe 51%, transparent 0%);
      border: solid 2px #E86056;
  }

  .tog-button-on{
        height: 35px;
        width: 55%;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: #E86056;
        color: white;
       // background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(196deg, #fffefe 8%, transparent 0);
        /* background-color: #E86056; */
        -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 103% 122%, 87% 0%, 0 0%);
        clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 103% 122%, 87% 0%, 0 0%);
        padding-top: 8px;
        cursor: pointer;
   }

    .tog-button-off{
        background-color: white;
        height: 30px;
        width: 51%;
        float: right;
        text-align: center;
        color: #E8E8E8;
        padding: 3px;
        padding-left: 15%;
        cursor: pointer;
        /* border: 1px solid #E8E8E8; */
      }


      .tog-button-on.Off{
          background-color: #B2B2B2;
          transform: translateX(43px);
          transition: all 0.2s linear;
          -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% -13%, 18% 120%, 397% 0%, 0 0%);
          clip-path: polygon(0% -13%, 18% 120%, 397% 0%, 0 0%);
      }

      .tog-button.Off{
           border:2px solid #B2B2B2;
       }

      .tog-button-on.On{
           background-color: #E86056;
           transform: translateX(0px);
           transition: all 0.2s linear;
           -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 305%, 101% 157%, 89% 0%, 0 0%);
           clip-path: polygon(0% 305%, 101% 157%, 89% 0%, 0 0%);
       }

      .tog-button.On{
           border:2px solid #E86056;
       }
```

Hope this helps.